# Touch response delay in Unity game on mobile devices

Tags: android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem with touch response lag in my Unity game on mobile devices, especially when firing the knife. On the computer everything works smoothly, however, after transferring the game to my phone I noticed a delay.

Here is the code snippet that handles the knife shot:

```html
using UnityEngine;

public class KnifeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    

    [SerializeField]
    private Vector2 throwForce;

    //knife shouldn't be controlled by the player when it's inactive 
    //(i.e. it already hit the log / another knife)
    private bool isActive = true;

    //for controlling physics
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    //the collider attached to Knife
    private PolygonCollider2D knifeCollider;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        knifeCollider = GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
    }
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource swist;
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource Gdzwiek;
    void Update()
    {
        //this method of detecting input also works for touch
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && isActive)
        {
            
            rb.AddForce(throwForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            GameController.Instance.GameUI.DecrementDisplayedKnifeCount();
            rb.gravityScale = 1;
            //once the knife isn't stationary, we can apply gravity (it will not automatically fall down)
            
            //Decrement number of available knives
            
            swist.Play();
        }
    }

    [SerializeField] private AudioSource Gloss;
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        //we don't even want to detect collisions when the knife isn't active
        if (!isActive)
            return;
        
         
        
         
        //if the knife happens to be active (1st collision), deactivate it
        isActive = false;

        //collision with a log
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Log")
        {
            
            GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
            Gdzwiek.Play();
            
            
            //stop the knife
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
            //this will automatically inherit rotation of the new parent (log)
            rb.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic;
            transform.SetParent(collision.collider.transform);

            //move the collider away from the blade which is stuck in the log
            knifeCollider.offset = new Vector2(knifeCollider.offset.x, -0.1f);
            

            //Spawn another knife
            GameController.Instance.OnSuccessfulKnifeHit();
        }

        //collision with another knife
        else if (collision.collider.tag == "Knife")
          

        {
            //start rapidly moving downwards
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, -2);
            //Game Over
            GameController.Instance.StartGameOverSequence(false);
            Gloss.Play();

        }
        

    }
}
```

I'm using Unity in the latest version, and I'm testing on an Android phone

Can anyone help me identify the cause of the delay? Is there something I should adjust in Rigidbody2D settings or other components?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

There may be many reasons for the error we encounter when performing touch operations on mobile devices. These include;

- Your game may have a low frame rate due to the low performance of mobile devices. Try to increase the performance of your game.
- Touch sensitivity varies from device to device. My recommendation is to test it on another mobile device.
- When you overload a particular function, it may respond late. I suggest you try `FixexUpdate` which works independently of `Update`.

These are just some of the things I can guess at the moment. There may be other reasons.

I have some additional suggestions.
First of all, try using `Input.GetTouch` instead of `Input.GetMouseButton`. Because Unity developed it especially for mobile devices.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isActive && Input.touchCount > 0 && TouchPhase.Began == Input.GetTouch(0).phase)
    {
        //Scripts...
}
```

If possible, move the blade according to its local coordinates.

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isActive && Input.touchCount > 0 && TouchPhase.Began == Input.GetTouch(0).phase)
        {
            Vector2 throwForceGlobal = transform.TransformDirection(throwForce);
            rb.AddForce(throwForceGlobal, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            GameController.Instance.GameUI.DecrementDisplayedKnifeCount();
            rb.gravityScale = 1;
            swist.Play();
            isActive = false;
        }
    }
```